# How to download files on Google drive with progress bar php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I download files on Google drive with progress bar from PHP https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=54fs54dg45f1f112f2

Comment: Please improve your question or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but given PHP executes serverside and I assume you want the client to see the search bar, it's not possible for a progress bar to be displayed.

Try JavaScript?